# Trouble with adding item into an NSMutableArray inside a block

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks

UPDATE:
I just found a tricky part... if I do something like this, it works:

```
[_friendsArrayInBlock insertObject:@"Bla" atIndex:itemIndex];
```

But it doesn't:

```
[_friendsArrayInBlock insertObject:friend atIndex:itemIndex];
```

Why I cannot add a custom object, but I can add NSString? What's the problem

ORIGINAL PART:
Here you can see the relevant code part:

```
@implementation ORGFriendsTableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *_friendsArray;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _friendsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    __block NSMutableArray *_friendsArrayInBlock = _friendsArray;

    [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                   id result,
                                                                   NSError *error) {
        FBGraphObject *fbGraphObject = (FBGraphObject *)result;

        NSMutableArray *userArray = fbGraphObject[@"data"];
        for (FBGraphObject *user in userArray) {

            ORGFBUser *friend = [[ORGFBUser alloc] initWithId:user[@"id"] name:user[@"name"] andPhotoURL:@"someurl"];

            NSInteger itemIndex = 0;
            [_friendsArrayInBlock insertObject:friend atIndex:itemIndex];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:itemIndex inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }];
}
```

The problem appears with on this line:

```
[_friendsArrayInBlock insertObject:friend atIndex:itemIndex];
```

Program recieving signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

I think it's related with block concept, and altering a non thread-safe NSMutableArray from it.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocks can access instance variables without using `__block` (see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW3)).  Therefore this should work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _friendsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                   id result,
                                                                   NSError *error) {
        FBGraphObject *fbGraphObject = (FBGraphObject *)result;

        NSMutableArray *userArray = fbGraphObject[@"data"];
        for (FBGraphObject *user in userArray) {

            ORGFBUser *friend = [[ORGFBUser alloc] initWithId:user[@"id"] name:user[@"name"] andPhotoURL:@"someurl"];

            NSInteger itemIndex = 0;
            [_friendsArray insertObject:friend atIndex:itemIndex];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:itemIndex inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Not only that, but if we wanted to keep `_friendsArrayInBlock`, he would still not need `__block`, because he's not assigning to it anywhere.

Comment: Technically, using `_friendsArrayInBlock` and using `_friendsArray` directly are different; the former stores the value of `_friendsArray` at the time the block is created, whereas the latter uses the value when the block is run; though it probably doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
@implementation ORGFriendsTableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *_friendsArray;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _friendsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    __block NSMutableArray *_friendsArrayInBlock = _friendsArray;

    [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                   id result,
                                                                   NSError *error) {
        FBGraphObject *fbGraphObject = (FBGraphObject *)result;

        NSMutableArray *userArray = fbGraphObject[@"data"];
        for (FBGraphObject *user in userArray) {

            ORGFBUser *friend = [[ORGFBUser alloc] initWithId:user[@"id"] name:user[@"name"] andPhotoURL:@"someurl"];

            [_friendsArrayInBlock addObject:friend];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_friendsArrayInBlock.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I gather you're replacing `insertObject:AtIndex:` with `addObject`? I wish you'd also tell us what you did so we don't have to do our own mental `diff` in order to figure it out...

Comment: 1. The problem the OP describes could not be caused by `insertObject`, and thus replacing `insertObject` with `addObject` will not help, but changes the behavior of the app; 2. I now notice that you're doing `reloadData`, too, but that's not necessary if you've done `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`.