# Load Facebook Friends into an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am currently trying to load a user's Facebook friends into an NSMutableArray. However, when I use `[users addObject: friend.name];` it doesn't add it to the array outside of the block of code. What am I missing here? Also I am trying to receive the number of friends and this also isn't working outside the block of code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {

        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
        [users addObject:friend.name];
        NSLog(@"%@",users);
    }
}];
```

**Full code here:** http://pastie.org/private/elynlgrkctakioi8pmtta.

Comment: I think this is because blocks can't normally access instance variables declared outside of the block. Take a look at this question (which incidentally is also about adding facebook friends): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804994/trouble-with-adding-item-into-an-nsmutablearray-inside-a-block

Comment: Are you sure you are actually fetching the friends? Have you put a breakpoint in the block to see? One thing to note is that if you are using the newest version of the API, you will only receive friends that have your app added to their Facebook account. Your entire list of friends is no longer attainable. So it is entirely possible you will end up with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is added in the array, but we have to wait sometime to complete the block process. I am fetching friends and storing in `NSMutableArray`. and use it after some delay of time. I am using below code.

```
 [FBSession setActiveSession:[self appDelegate].session];
    FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) 
    {
         NSLog(@"name : %@",[friend name]);

         [tempArray addObject:friend];
      }
}];

[self performSelector:@selector(afterFetchingFbFriend:) withObject:tempArray afterDelay:10.0];
```

in 10.0 delay it completes the block process and i have all the friends in my array.
and then my method to process array is :

```
-(void)afterFetchingFbFriend:(NSMutableArray *)tempArray
{
     //do something.
}
```

if not getting in 10.0 delay time then increase it as it depends on internet speed so the fetching friends time may be different. It works for me.